# Swift3 CoreData crash on iOS9 device

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, ios9.3

I have CoreData app that is perfectly working on iOS10, written in Swift3, supporting iOS 8.4 and above.

When I try to run it on iOS 9.3.5 I'm getting error:

```
2016-10-07 17:47:20.596 FormApp[710:179733] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'
```

crashing on line:

```
form.addToOpenQuestions(openQuestion)
```

I have added @objc() to managed object classes. Then I'm getting new error:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'FormApp.Form' for entity 'Form'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

It is happening on line:

```
let form = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Form", into: managedObjectContext) as! Form
```

My config:

[image: Settings of enity]

[image: Class]

[image: Model]

[image: Properties extension]

All classes were generated by Xcode. I have tried deleting Module and all configurations. Anyone have idea how to make it work?

Comment: Can you set an Exception breakpoint and show the exact line where the app crashes? Select breakpoints tab in xCode -> "+" button in the bottom left corner -> Exception Breakpoint. Also please show Form+CoreDataProperties.swift file

Comment: @alex Done. Added screen and lines

Comment: Do you have Arrangment: Ordered checkmark in your core data model? For some reason it is expecting NSSet, but your NSManagedObject code has NSOrderedSet, which is a subclass of NSObject. Try to remove that checkmark and refactor those relationships to NSSet

Comment: @alex make it as Your answer. Works. Why it is working on iOS10 and not on iOS9? They make NSOrderedSet subclass of NSSet in this new version or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason NSSet is expected, but your NSManagedObject code has NSOrderedSet, which is a subclass of NSObject. Try to remove "Arrangment: Ordered" checkmark in your core data model and refactor those relationships to NSSet.
Not sure why this happens in iOS 10 but not in iOS 9 though.

P.S. Perhaps you should reconsider your Core Data model? It looks like your Open/Closed questions are going to change their status. If so, I would recommend to make one Question entity with `closed` bool or `status` int.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with iOS 9.3

The issue was same as mention by @alex above and i have solve as below

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        // use iOS 11-only feature
        YOUR_CLASS.insertIntoClosedQuestion(YOUR_OBJECT, at: index)
    } else {
        // handle older versions
        let orderset:NSMutableOrderedSet = Form.closeQuestion as! NSMutableOrderedSet
        orderset.insert(YOUR_OBJECT, at: index)
        YOUR_CLASS.addToClosedQuestion(orderset)
    }
```

Hope it will helpful to others.